# FFMPEG get jpeg data buffer from mjpeg stream?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, mjpeg

I'm using `FFMPEG` to decode video stream from IP Camera, I have the example code that can decode video stream with any codec into `YUI` frames format.

But my case is special, I will describe as below

The IP camera stream is `MJPEG`, and I want using `FFMPEG` to decode, but I don't want to decode frame into `YUV`, I want to decode frame under `jpeg` format, and save those `jpeg` buffer into image files `(*.jpg)`.

So far, I can do it by converting `YUV` frame (after decoding) to `Jpeg`, but this will cause bad performance. Since video stream is `MJPEG`, I think I can get `jpeg` data before decoding to `YUI`, but I don't know how to do it.

Someone can help me?

Many thanks,

T&T